# Better way of doing this? List index assignment in C#

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, object, indexing

So, this code works. But I feel I'm missing something fundamental here. Assigning an int to the List Index to access them just doesn't feel right. Surely there is a better way to go about this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]

public class ResourceHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Basic resources setup.
    List<Resource> BasicResources = new List<Resource>();

    // I want to avoid doing this, it seems dumb.
    int Food = 0;
    int Power = 1;
    int Matter = 2;
    int People = 3;
            
    private void Start()
    {
        BasicResources.Add(new Resource("Food", 10));
        BasicResources.Add(new Resource("Power", 10));
        BasicResources.Add(new Resource("Matter", 100));
        BasicResources.Add(new Resource("People", 5));

        // This makes sense.
        foreach (Resource resource in BasicResources)
        {
            Debug.Log(resource.Type + ", " + resource.Value);
        }

        //This works, but seems like a dumb way to do it.
        BasicResources[Food].AddValue(10);
        BasicResources[Power].AddMultiplier(0.25f);
    }

}
```

Comment: You might be better off using a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` instead of a `List<T>`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: If you only have these four things, and always have these four things, just create a struct with these four things as members.

Comment: If you're hardcoding an int for these 4 things then seemingly you're making a compile time decision that you won't have any other kind of things, so how about you make these a subclass of a class?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need an enum for what you are trying to achieve with the type of resources?

...BasicResources.Add(new Resource(ResourceType.Food, 10));

And then search your resource by enum
BasicResources. First (x=> x.Type== ResourceType.Food).AddValue(10)

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum ResourceType { Food, Power, Matter, People };

public class Resource
{
    public ResourceType Type { get; private set; }
    public int Value { get; private set; }

    public Resource(ResourceType type, int value)
    {
        Type = type;
        Value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    { 
        return Type + ", " + Value; 
    }
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
        
public class ResourceHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Basic resources setup.
    List<Resource> BasicResources = new List<Resource>();
        
                    
    private void Start()
    {
        BasicResources.Add(new Resource(ResourceType.Food, 10));
        BasicResources.Add(new Resource(ResourceType.Power, 10));
        BasicResources.Add(new Resource(ResourceType.Matter, 100));
        BasicResources.Add(new Resource(ResourceType.People, 5));
        
        foreach (Resource resource in BasicResources)
        {
            Debug.Log(resource);
        }

        //This works, but seems like a dumb way to do it.
        BasicResources[Food].AddValue(10);
        BasicResources[Power].AddMultiplier(0.25f);
    }
}
```